# Gradual ramp down in in number of users observed in line with HPA taking down locust worker pods

Tags: performance-testing, locust

I've recently deployed locust 2.15.1 into a kubernetes cluster v1.25.10 via locust helm chart version 0.31.5. I have HPA enabled and configured like so:

```
  hpa:
    enabled: true
    minReplicas: 5
    maxReplicas: 100
    targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

During my load tests I'm seeing this unwanted and unexpected behaviour whereby some minutes after locust has hit the specified number of users, the horizontal pod autoscaler starts to gradually downscale by removing locust worker pods, in accordance with the configuration above. This is fine except with each worker pod that HPA removes, the user load is also reduced leading to a gradual step down of the load until the minimum number of locust workers is reached i.e. the minReplicas value above.

[image]

Whenever a worker is removed by HPA something like the following is logged by the locust master:

[2024-01-05 15:15:11,778] locust-master-54b7d9b998-wwjtq/INFO/locust.runners: Worker 'locust-worker-79fbc94fbf-ntqqj_0c9efb47081c463c8ae94258ce52d5bc' (index 2) quit. 0 workers ready.

Does anyone have any advice on how to avoid this unwanted ramp down in load that coincides with locust worker pod scale down?

Comment: Never auto-scale workers. But if you absolutely have to, use the `--enable-rebalancing`parameter to move users to the remaining workers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Cyberwiz. I applied the --enable-rebalancing flag to the master but it led to some very erratic fluctuations in the user count so we wont use it. Applying a stabilizationWindowSeconds value to the HPA config has helped since HPA wont consider scaling down until this window has passed, so setting it to longer than the required test duration works. Other than that, yeh we can always set a static number of worker replicas and try not to forget to scale them down manually afterwards :)